# The Right Way to Account for Daylight Savings Time in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've been working in Django (1.11) and Python (3.5.3) with tracking events that repeat from week to week or month to month, and have encountered a small issue when the jump across a DST change occurs.

As an example, say a movie is shown every Wednesday at 2pm. At a certain point in November, the time currently switches to 1pm when the DST is no longer active. That isn't the desired behavior - if an event is at 2pm, it should remain at 2pm regardless of DST.

Right now, I'm handling it with:

```
new_start_date = old_start_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
```

And it works, but I also know it throws a warning in the background.

Is there a better way to account for that hour discrepancy?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to keep the time the same in UTC, ie make it an hour earlier in local time?

Comment: Oh! No, and I see where I worded that poorly: the event - if it's at 2pm - should always be at 2pm local time regardless of DST.

Comment: How are you representing "every Wednesday at 2pm" in your model / database?

Comment: If an event is marked as occurring weekly during a given period, the first instance is entered manually, and subsequent instances are created by creating a copy of the event, removing the event.pk, reassigning the start_date with the timedelta operation in the OP, and saving the new instance. It's all working, I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way.